# How to slide rows in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table and script bellow. Main idea is to change data in table rows every 3 seconds...so first time it will be 1, after 3 seconds it will be 2 and so on. When i use this script data get crazy(displays first row and thats it). Can someone help me and tell me what i need to change?

**HTML**

```
 <table>

    <tr>
        <th>naslov1</th>
        <th>naslov2</th>
        <th>naslov3</th>
    </tr>


    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <tbody id="tableslide">
            <tr>

                <td>test_@i</td>
                <td>test_@i</td>
                <td>test_@i</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    }


</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#tableslide > tr:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function () {

        $('#tableslide >tr:first')
          .slideToggle(1)
          //.fadeOut(300)
          .next()

          //.fadeIn(300)
          .slideToggle(1)
          .end()
          .appendTo('#tableslide');
</script>

    }, 3000);

});
```

I want to display first three rows per one slide...and then second two rows

Comment: `When i use this script data get crazy` - that's a very vague error description.

Comment: they display only one row and then nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix the HTML to put the `<tbody>` and `</tbody>` tags outside the loop, otherwise you have one tbody per row.

```
<tbody id="tableslide">
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>test_@i</td>
        <td>test_@i</td>
        <td>test_@i</td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

`.slideUp()`, `.slideDown()`, `.slideToggle()` don't work reliably on table rows, but you can use `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` as follows :

```
$(function () {
    var selectors = [
        ":lt(3)",
        ":gt(2)"
    ];
    var $tableslide = $("#tableslide").children(selectors[1]).hide().end();
    var state = false;
    setInterval(function () {
        var s = state;
        $tableslide.children(selectors[+s]).fadeOut().promise().then(function () {
            $tableslide.children(selectors[+!s]).fadeIn();
        });
        state = !state;
    }, 3000);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gtd4f5ny/)**

Comment: its not working and also i want to display 3 rows per one slide ... and then on second slide to display rest of them...in this case thats 2 rows test4 and test5

Comment: OK, I've had another hack at the code and added a Demo.

Comment: just one question...is it possible to do this dynamically...for example if increase number of element to 9 that i get 3 rows slides 3 times? so that i get 1,2,3 slide to 4,5,6 slide to 7,8,9 ??

Comment: Yes, that's possible though the code will differ in a couple of regards. For example, the `state` would probably need to be an integer instead of a boolean, and the `selectors` would need to be dynamically generated. It may be simpler to do adopt a different approach entirely. Give it a try and if you run into difficulty, then post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is outside your table body, so you'll end up with i amount of tables with the same id. I presume you want to add a row for each loop iteration instead?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xn9zL1k2/) is a fiddle with the loop in the correct place (giving 3 rows in the example)

```
<tbody id="tableslide">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@i</td>
            <td>@i</td>
            <td>@i</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: can i display 3 rows per page? Something like <tr><td>1</td<td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr> and then slide on <tr><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr>.....if u know what i mean?